# Why does a TimeWithZone object act differently, based on how it was created, especially regarding `.offset`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
>> DateTime.now.in_time_zone.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
>> Time.zone.now.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
>> DateTime.now.in_time_zone.offset
=> (0/1)
>> Time.zone.now.offset
NoMethodError: undefined method `offset' for Mon, 28 Aug 2017 17:34:46 CEST +02:00:Time
    from /Users/Magne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.16/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:364:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):287
    from /Users/Magne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/Magne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/Magne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/Magne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Magne/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-4.1.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` doesn't have an `offset` method. Instead, the call is handled by [`method_missing`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-method_missing):

> Send the missing method to `time` instance, and wrap result in a new TimeWithZone with the existing `time_zone`.

It works for `DateTime` because it responds to `offset`:

```
DateTime.instance_methods.include? :offset
#=> true
```

And fails for `Time` because it does not:

```
Time.instance_methods.include? :offset
#=> false
```

Comment: So, a DateTime object made into a TimeWithZone object is actually merely casted, and not re-created? That would explain why the pre-existing .offset method from the DateTime class persists..